# Recuperar las etiquetas de un alimento

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo una relación Many To Many entre Alimentos y Etiquetas. 
El problema está en que cuando quiero editar un alimento en la vista para editarlo, quiero recuperar las diferentes etiquetas asignadas pero éstas se recogen en la vista de creación mediante un checkbox y me gustaría que apareciera en la vista edición el checkbox marcado.

A continuación pongo el código que estoy utilizando:

- AlimentoController:

  ```
  public function create() {
  return view('Alimento/crear');
  }

  public function store(Request $request)        {
  $this-> validate($request,
  ['nombre'=>'required', 'kcal'=>'required', 'proteinas'=>'required', 'carbohidratos'=>'required','grasas'=>'required'  ]);

  $etiqueta=new Etiqueta();
  $alimento = new Alimento();

  $alimento->nombre = $request->nombre;
  $alimento->kcal = $request->kcal;
  $alimento->grasas = $request->grasas;
  $alimento->proteinas=$request->proteinas;
  $alimento->carbohidratos=$request->carbohidratos;

  $etiqueta->etiqueta=$request->etiqueta;
  $alimento->etiquetas()->attach($etiqueta->id);

  $etiqueta->save();
  $alimento->save();

  }

  public function edit($id) {
  $alimento = Alimento::find($id);
  $etiquetas= $alimento->etiquetas();
  return view ('Alimento/editar')->with(['alimento'=>$alimento, 'etiquetas'=>$etiquetas]);
   }

  public function update(Request $request, $id){

  $this-> validate($request,
      ['nombre'=>'required', 'kcal'=>'required', 'proteinas'=>'required', 'carbohidratos'=>'required',
          'grasas'=>'required'  ]);


  $alimento = Alimento::find($id);
  $etiqueta = $alimento->etiquetas();

  $alimento->nombre = $request->nombre;
  $alimento->kcal = $request->kcal;
  $alimento->grasas = $request->grasas;
  $alimento->proteinas=$request->proteinas;
  $alimento->carbohidratos=$request->carbohidratos;
  $etiqueta->etiqueta=$request->etiqueta;



  $etiqueta->save();
  $alimento->save();

  if($alimento->save()){
      return redirect('alimentos');
  }else{
      return back()->with('nmsj','No se ha actualizado el alimento correctamente');
  }

  }
  ```
- Vista Crear-Alimento (porción de código para recoger las etiquetas):

```html
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="etiqueta" value="pescados"><strong>Pescados y mariscos</strong></label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="etiqueta" value="carnes"><strong>Carnes y derivados cárnicos</strong></label>
 </div>
 <div class="checkbox">
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="etiqueta" value="huevos"><strong>Huevos</strong></label>
 </div>
 <div class="checkbox">
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="etiqueta" value="cereales"><strong>Cereales</strong></label>
 </div>
```

- Vista Editar-Alimento (porción de código para recuperar las etiquetas)

```html
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="etiqueta" value="pescados" {{$alimento->etiquetas()=='pescados' ? 'checked':''}}><strong>Pescados y mariscos</strong></label>
 </div>
 <div class="checkbox">
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="etiqueta" value="carnes" {{$alimento->etiquetas()=='carnes' ? 'checked':''}}><strong>Carnes y derivados cárnicos</strong></label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="etiqueta" value="huevos" {{$alimento->etiquetas()=='huevos' ? 'checked':''}}><strong>Huevos</strong></label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="etiqueta" value="cereales" {{$alimento->etiquetas()=='cereales' ? 'checked':''}}><strong>Cereales</strong></label>
 </div>
```

Muchas gracias !

Comment: ¿qué valor contiene `$alimento->etiquetas()`? Yo sé que es una consulta a la relación, pero me gustaría saber que aparece en un `dump()` de la misma.

Comment: no sera que el resultado de $alimento->etiquetas() es un array y lo estas comparando con una cadena??? quizas debieras hacer algo como: <label><input type="checkbox" name="etiqueta" value="cereales" {{ **in_array('cereales', $alimento->etiquetas()) ? 'checked':''**}}><strong>Cereales</strong></label>

Comment: @Shaz el valor que devuelve dump($alimento->etiquetas()) es muy largo pero copio la primera parte de la respuesta (Si quisieras ver otra en concreto dígamelo): BelongsToMany {#241 ▼
  #table: "alimento_etiqueta"
  #foreignKey: "alimento_id"
  #relatedKey: "etiqueta_id"
  #relationName: "etiquetas"
  #pivotColumns: []
  #pivotWheres: []
  #pivotWhereIns: []
  #pivotCreatedAt: null
  #pivotUpdatedAt: null
  #using: null

Comment: @Jakala con in_array necesito que $alimento->etiquetas() sea un array y al probarlo me devuelve un error diciendo que $alimento->etiquetas() no es un array

Answer (score 0):

Estás confundiendo `$alimento->etiquetas()` y `$alimento->etiquetas`.

`$alimento->etiquetas()` es una consulta que haces directamente a la relación, por lo cual como puedes ver en el dump, te da un objeto de tipo `BelongsToMany`.

`$alimento->etiquetas` es una propiedad dinámica o "mágica" que contiene normalmente una colección compuesta por los elementos (etiquetas) relacionados con dicho alimento.

Si lo que deseas es comparar con `in_array()` (asumiendo que sea unidimensional) o similar, entonces deberás usar la propiedad dinámica en vez de la consulta a la relación.

```
in_array('etiqueta1', $alimento->etiquetas)
```